# Docker internals/architecture

Tags: docker

I've started using Docker but I want to understand it better ( a bit better). So, I am searching for a book/article to get information how it works internally ( on the OS level). I suppose that it cannot be easy subject but it should be easier than real virtualization.

I am asking for referencing me to any book/an article. I tried to find any book but I didn't find something about Docker internals.

Answer (score 38):

Docker doesn't really have any *internals*. It's simply a golang binary wrapped around a bunch of tooling that already exists in the kernel, such as:

- [cgroups](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/ch01.html) to limit an applications available resources
- [namespaces](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html) to provide isolation from other containers
- [Union Filesystems](https://lwn.net/Articles/312641/) to provide fast, light access to storage

I would recommend reading about how those three technologies work before trying to understand what else docker does, as docker simply provides a more accessible API/command line tooling for these technologies.

Here's some links for further reading:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/docker-overview/#the-underlying-technology

https://washraf.gitbooks.io/the-docker-ecosystem/content/Chapter%201/Section%203/techniques_behind_docker.html

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/using-docker/9781491915752/ch04.html

Answer (score 2):

as @Frap linked (namespaces, cgroups, UFS) but also look at storage drivers for docker https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/selectadriver/

If you want to peak under the hood there is a nice project here https://github.com/mhausenblas/cinf

The other part of note is the networking side of docker and storage drivers etc. the docker docs are a reasonable primer on this https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/